# Control absolute position of `minipage` or image on page

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I am producing a 30x30cm book with a lot of images. I would like to control the absolute positioning of a `minipage` (to allow normal flowing text) and some sort of `image` environment to allow me to make pages that look like this:

[image]

Ideally, I would like a form that looks like `\begin{minipage}{x1, y1}{width, height}`, where (x1,y1) is the top left corner.

Would it be possible to achieve this with `tikz` while still keeping the minipage environment so I can do "normal" text? Or does anyone have a more elegant solution that would meet these requirements?

I'm happy to hear other suggestions if I am going about this the wrong way!

Thanks!
David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the [`textpos` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos), which provides absolute positioning facilities.
You should use it with the `absolute` package option, and it will provide a `\textblock` environment that should meet your needs.

Usage:

```
\begin{textblock}{hsize}(hpos,vpos)
    text...
\end{textblock}
```

The package provides more features (grid placement, coloured blocks, etc..), have a look at [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/textpos/textpos.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Tonio, that's exactly what I was looking for! I'll post up a working example once I have got my head around it.